# Codeigniter getting result from model

Tags: database, codeigniter, model

i have a controller called main...
here i have this code.

```
$data['companies'] = $this->companies->getAllCompanies();
$this->load->view('main_view',$data);
```

i have loaded the model called companies in the contructer like this:

```
$this->load->model('companies');
```

and this is my model:

```
class Companies extends CI_Model{    
 function getAllCompanies()
 {
       $this -> db -> select('*');
       //$this -> db -> from('companies');

       $query = $this -> db -> get('companies');

       if($query -> num_rows() > 0)
       {
         return $query->result();
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }
 }}
```

i am getting this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\awt\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_driver.php on line 193
Call Stack

5   0.0299  4303144 Companies->getAllCompanies( )   ..\main.php:32
```

whats wrong in this code plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that you have some kind of sql error. Try enabling the `db_debug` flag in `application/config/database.php` and check the table names and such. You can try to print the generated sql query at where at the place of the error too (under system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php:191).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Companies extends CI_Model{    
 function getAllCompanies()
 {
       $this -> db -> select('*');
       //$this -> db -> from('companies');

       $result = $this -> db -> get('companies');

       if($query -> num_rows() > 0)
       {
         return $result;
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }
 }}
```

make the above changes.